# how to generate my xml coverture report of all my project

Tags: python-3.x, sonarqube, pytest

I reach to generate the xml file with a single test file but I can not generate for my entire project. AND how to include this xml (for the whole project) in `SonaQube7.9.1`I Use `Coverage4.5.4`.

`-Project
------sources
-----------__init__.py
-----------file1.py
-----------filen.py
------test
-----------__init__.py
-----------testFile1.py
-----------testFilen.py`

Comment: even the single xml file I generated, I can not see its results on the sonar dashboard. it always displays 0 cover. `sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=C:/Users/Desktop/Project/test/coverage.xml`
`sonar.sources=C:/Users/Desktop/Project/sources`. AND 
`cmd windows` is
`C:\Users\Desktop\Project\sources>sonar-scanner`

Comment: Just update your question; do not add comments yourself. What have you researched? Any issues in the logs?

Comment: I find the solution. I just installed `plugin pytest-cov`.then `py.test --cov=sources` commande. Finally `coverage xml`